# converting javascript algebraically

Tags: javascript, algebra

I've been trying a very long time and haven't been able to do this.

```
prize = slices - 1 - Math.floor(degrees / (360 / slices));
```

Ive been trying to get degrees by itself giving price the value of, lets assume, 3 and slices 8

```
3 = 8 - 1 - Math.floor(degrees / (360 / 8));
```

I am trying to get

```
degrees =
```

Comment: `degrees = 360*(slices - prize - 1)/slices`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't do algebra internally. You have to solve the equation for that.

You should write a function that takes `prize` and `slices` as parameters, and returns the `degrees` - once you solve the equation.

```js
// prize = slices - 1 - Math.floor(degrees / (360 / slices));

function getDegrees (prize, slices) {
  return -(prize - slices + 1) * (360 / slices);
}

console.log(getDegrees(3,8));
```

Comment: You're welcome. Since this is your first question on the site, do read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).